# Cookie Access over JSONP

Tags: ajax, cookies, jsonp

I have a page in `domain.com` that makes a JSONP ajax request (using jQuery's `.getJSON()` function) to a URL in `anotherdomain.com`. I thought (read: assumed) that the resource in `anotherdomain.com` would have server-side access to any cookies set in that domain, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

The ajax call is being done specifically to access a particular cookie, do some data manipulation and return a rich set of information keyed by the cookie value. The original domain doesn't have direct access to the cookie value, so I thought that an ajax request would maintain the state I need.

Which pivotal piece of information about cookies am I overlooking? I'm exhausted and I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found a way of doing it, but it looks like JSONP to my eye, so I'm wondering why this way works while the Ajax version doesn't. Is the request just disconnected from the browser session so that no cookies are accessible?

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="<?php echo $service_url . '&callback=interests' ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function interests( data ) {
    $( function() {
      var c_behaviors = data.length;
      var ids         = [];

      for( var i = 0; i < c_behaviors; i++ ) {
        ids.push( data[i].behavior_id );
      }

      $('body').append( '<p><label>Returned:</label> ' + ids.join( ', ' ) + '</p>' );       
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am sure you may have tripled checked this, but how sure are you that the cookie was set by anotherdomain.com? Moreover, what is the state of the cookie being set, such as expiration, path etc.

Comment: Yeah. If I alert the target URL before the ajax call and then load the target URL in a new tab, I get exactly what I expect to get. It seems that the Ajax call is more disconnected from the browser session than I thought.

Comment: Try the $.ajax call with type "json" and see what kind of results you get. BTW, your JSONP approach was documented http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421245/make-getjson-in-jquery-to-pass-cookies-to-external-domain and did work for someone else too

Comment: Thanks for the update, Salman. That question never came up in my searches, but looks like _exactly_ what I'm trying to do. I don't know why it's not working for me. A regular JSON call won't work since it's a cross-domain request.

Comment: Rob, can you explain what your "way of doing it" is? Is that referring to the script snippet at the bottom of the question? Did embedding the scripts in the actual HTML work as opposed to using a jQuery $.getJSON call? Both methods work when I have "accept third-party cookies" checked in FF, but neither works when it is unchecked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The same origin policy applies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) to all ajax requests, so if the domain being accessed in an ajax call is different than the domain loaded in the browser (document.host), all cookies associated with the domain in the requested url will not be sent up. Therefore, the JSONP approach works because it writes out a new script tag in the window, which will behave like any resource request a browser could make to an external domain (hence passing all the cookies associated with the domain in the url). I have also confirmed this by simply calling `$.post("http://atdmt.com")` from my chrome console, while on stackoverflow.com in the browser (the only other domain that had cookies in my browser, while writing up the answer) and it did not send up any cookies in the request headers.

Another solution to get around the problem of maintaining state for **anotherdomain.com** would be to have **anotherdomain.com** set a first party cookie (by not setting the domain attribute of the cookie) and when an ajax/json request is made to **anotherdomain.com** access those cookies via javascript and push them up the request using standard HTTP params.

Hope I have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem before.  The issue I found is that most browsers won't let you ESTABLISH a session (i.e. set a session cookie) when the same origin policy isn't being met.