# Accessing cookies in tornado over ajax calls in flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, tornado

As on overview I have a Flask app which serves as the main website and a Tornado app that serves as the chat server for the website, each running independent on a separate port.

The chat app directly reads the session information from flask,

`self.get_cookie(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)`

The problem that I am having is that if I access the chat server through the browser the session will read but using an Ajax call the session does not.

The chat server provides the Access-Control-Allow-Domain header to allow for the Cross-Domain call.

The ajax is very simple,

`$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8888', {'message': 'test'}, function(){});`

The cookies domain is simply set to `127.0.0.1` and is not an HTTP only cookie.

Is there any particular reason I can access the cookie in my browser at `127.0.0.1:8888` and not the Ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/wiki/APIDocumentation

From my research it appears that cross-domain ajax calls DO NOT send cookie information in the request headers, using the above library allowed for a workaround.

Note this is similar to

[Cookie Access over JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249205/cookie-access-over-jsonp)

In addition JSONP responses MUST be sent wrapped in the provided callback GET parameter, otherwise an error with be thrown.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

E.g.

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/chat/get_messages?callback=jsonp`

Responds

```
jsonp(
    {
        'data': '1',
        'result': true 
    }
)
```