# php get cookie set by another server

Tags: php

I know I am asking how to get the cross-domain cookies and that is traditionally not possible but we have a situation where we had two servers `site1.domain.com` and `site2.domain.com` and we had a cookie based SSO which was working fine until the company decided to move `site2.domain.com` to a completely different domain. Now the problem is, when someone logs in to `site1.domain.com`, we set a cookie for the `.domain.com.`

I want to check if there's a cookie from `domain2.com`, which is the new domain of the second server.

I tried curl to call a page called getCookie.php, which just gets the cookie and sends the response back but curl initiates a completely new session and doesn't pretend to be a user who is browsing the site2.domain2.com

Is there any way, I can read that cookie value from site2? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe embedding an iframe could help?

Comment: If you've got control over both servers, you can probably put something together using API calls, too.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP?

Load a "JS-file" from site1.domain.com and return the requested cookie information as json.

**EDIT**

site1.domain.com/getCookie.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');
echo 'callback('.json_encode($_COOKIE).');';
?>
```

and on the site2.domain2.com html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script >function callback(data) { ... }</script>
  <script src="site1.domain.com/getCookie.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

You may find more information at [Cookie Access over JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249205/cookie-access-over-jsonp)

Comment: This is new to me.. Can you please provide me a rough example? I will really appreciate that.

Comment: your callback javascript function needs to process the information and store the sso cookie at this domain as well.

Comment: Here is what I tried in my getCookie.php on server1
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript'); 
echo "callback(".json_ecode($_COOKIE['company']).");";
?>
And here is what I have on server 2 as simple html file..<html>
<head>
<script>
function callback(data) { 
alert(data);
}

</script>
<script src="http://site1.domain.com/getCookie.php" type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
This doesn't seem to be working

Comment: did you debug your site2 site? it works pretty well for me. to be honest, i'm working on internal domains at the moment. But the same origin policy should work here as well.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer: it's json_encode not json_ecode.

Comment: I finally made the code to work but cross domain it is not printing my cookie in alert.. I get rest of the things to show up in alert. When I execute the same script from server1, it prints alerts with the cookie value.. I have actually currently two domain name point to the same IP to test this scenerio